# How to filter html tags with Python

Tags: python, html, text, filter

I have the html document with an article. I have some amount of tags, that I can use for text formatting. But my text editor uses a lot of unnecessary tags for formatting. I want to write a program in Python for filtering these tags. 
What would be the major logic(structure, strategy) of such a program? I'm beginner in Python and want to learn this language through solving real practical task. But I need some general overview to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html_string = # the HTML code
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
print parsed_html.body.find('div', attrs = {attrs inside html code}).text
```

Here, `div` is just the tag, you can use any tag whose text you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear on your requirements but you should use ready-made parsers like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in python.

You can find a [tutorial here](http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html)

Answer (score 0):

just don't know about what will be missed, but you can use regex.

```
re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', text)
```

the above function will search...

otherwise you can use htmlparser

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        self.fed.append('&%s;' % name)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def html_to_text(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```